# angular 6 removeAt and trackBy update formArray but not correctly dom

Tags: angular, formarray

I add and delete, `formArray` in a `formGroup`.
I track the id's to delete with `trackBy`.

The good index pass to the function `delete(i)` and remove the good `formArray` element in the form, but in dom, the last one disappears each time.

I need this trackBy, otherwise, when I write inside input's, i lose the focus :-(.

[my code simplified](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o5jqug?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

I tried when delete; filter but my objects is `FormArray` or `AbstractControl`[]

Comment: You can change your html trackBy to this: trackBy:trackByFn(i, item).  You are calling the trackByFn but not passing the variables needed

Comment: Dix you tried your solution ? Because i lost the focus when write on then like i had no trackby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the formArrayName must be outside the *ngFor, and the *ngFor is over get('contacts').controls

```
<div formArrayName="contacts" class="bloc-border bloc-color">
     <div *ngFor="let item of siteForm.get('contacts').controls; 
           let i = index; " [formGroupName]="i">
           <div class="col-sm-12" style="display:flex;">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControlName]="'type'">
              - {{i}}
              <button  type="button"  (click)="deleteContact(i)">DELETE</button>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
Sometimes using directy siteForm.get('contact').controls, give us an error (I think in some versions of Anglar, but I'm not sure). To avoid we can create a getter thar return a formArray

```
get contacts():FormArray|null
{
    return this.siteForm?this.siteForm.get('contacts') as FormArray:null
}
```

And use

```
<div *ngFor="let item of contacts.controls;...>
```

Comment: Ok perfect it works like a charm, sad had no solution to use the trackBy for optimisation of changing all dom, but i have still an wierd message in vue "ng: Identifier 'controls' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member"  maybe my ide ?

Comment: about the error, check my updated answer (I think that in newer version of Angular is solved)

Answer (score 2):

This happen because you are using trackBy Index.

Use: trackBy: trackElement

It solve my problem

Comment: that solved my problem: ```trackByFn(item: any) {
    return item;
  }```. I had by index before and it wasn't working. Now works correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
deleteContact(position: any) {
const ctrl = this.siteForm.controls.contacts as FormArray;
while (ctrl.length - 1 > position) {
  const center = ctrl.controls[position + 1].value;
  ctrl.controls[position + 1].patchValue(ctrl.controls[position].value);
  ctrl.controls[position].patchValue(center);

  position ++;
}
ctrl.removeAt(ctrl.length - 1);
```

}

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.